# DBnull to integer conversion error

Tags: database, vb.net

I get the `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid." error on the line "Dim avgObject As string = Cstr(avgCom.ExecuteScalar())`

The command works when the `where module_ID='" & moduleSelect & "'` statement is removed and I do not know how to fix this, can anyone help?

```
    Dim moduleSelect As String = moduleRadio.SelectedValue
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Using avgCom As New SqlCommand("SELECT AVG(exam) FROM completed_module where module_ID='" & moduleSelect & "' ", _
                                        connection)
            connection.Open()
            Dim avgObject As Integer = CInt(avgCom.ExecuteScalar())
            Dim averageVar As String
            averageVar = avgObject.ToString
            avgLabel.Text = averageVar
        End Using
```

Comment: A google search for `Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.` has nearly 8000 results.

Comment: Can you run the query `SELECT AVG(exam).. where Module_ID = nnn`? I think, it is returning null because there aren't records for the module_ID you passed in.

Comment: There were no values selected from the list when the page loaded thus giving the null, thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this, first checking if it is dbnull:

```
Dim moduleSelect As String = moduleRadio.SelectedValue

Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    Using avgCom As New SqlCommand("SELECT AVG(exam) FROM completed_module where module_ID='" & moduleSelect & "' ", _
                                    connection)
        connection.Open()
        Dim result = avgCom.ExecuteScalar()
        If IsDBNull(result) then return
        Dim avgObject As Integer = CInt(result)
        Dim averageVar As String
        averageVar = avgObject.ToString
        avgLabel.Text = averageVar
    End Using
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped after 8 years...

Answer (score 2):

`DBNull` means that the record in the database does not contain a value for the column. So basically you are trying to convert "nothing" into a number.

What do you want your program to do? Skip the row? Use a default value instead?

If the command *really* "works" if you remove a statement from the command, I suggest you simply remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToString instead. Directcast as string does not work for Null/Nothing

**UPDATE**
Problem happens whenever you do not receive any results.

I tested, so CStr to Convert.ToString works for DBNUll, but CInt and Convert.ToIntXX still throws an eception.
You can use

```
Dim scalarResult = avgCom.ExecuteScalar()
If Convert.IsDBNull(scalarResult) then
  avgObject = 0
Else
  avgObject = Convert.toInt32(scalarResult)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error :**`Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

This error Occurs because your query return a `NULL` value.. you can manage the `NULL` value by using the Below code..

Try like below it will help you...

```
connection.Open()
Dim result As String = avgCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
Dim avgObject As Integer = If(result = "", 0, CInt(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this fails because there is a value missing. (i.e. NULL)
But it might work if you default to 0 if a row with NULL was encountered:

```
SELECT AVG(ISNULL(exam,0)) FROM completed_module where module_ID=
```

Otherwise make sure your table does not include NULL-values for that column:

```
UPDATE completed_module SET exam = 0 WHERE exam IS NULL
```

(maybe constraint it so it may not have future NULL-Values also ;))

EDIT: this assumes that you can actually have an average value for every row, even those where the column you access is NULL, in that case i would assume NULL does not add anything to your average value (which the other rows that share that ID might) so I default it to 0